# Displaying the elements of an array that are an array

Tags: javascript, angular

Gets the elements that are stored in history. History is an array and each element of the array is a different array that contains fields with name and value. I would like to display this history table in the following way. It iterates over each element of the array and displays each element (array) in the table (two columns, one name, second value). That is, array a is displayed as follows:
No. 1
Surname Jan
Firstname John etc.
Currently, every board in history is displayed this way
1 row is the field names and the second is the values ​​and I would like it to be done as I wrote.

```
export class AllDataEntryHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}
  @Input() modificationHistory: any;
  history: any[] = [];
  pom: any[] = [];

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'lp',
    'objectId',
    'registrarName',
    'registrarSurname',
    'registrarId',
    'entryDate',
    'registrarModName',
    'registrarModSurname',
    'registrarModId',
    'modificationDate',
    'state'
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.modificationHistory && this.modificationHistory.changeLogDtos) {
      this.history = this.modificationHistory.changeLogDtos
        .filter((entry: ChangeLogDto) => entry.type === 'REFUSAL_OF_ENTRY')
        .flatMap((entry: ChangeLogDto) => entry.changeLogEntries)
        .map((entry: ChangeLogEntryDto) => {
          return {
            lp: entry.lp,
            objectId: entry.objectId,
            registrarName: entry.registrarName,
            registrarSurname: entry.registrarSurname,
            registrarId: entry.registrarId,
            entryDate: entry.entryDate,
            registrarModName: entry.registrarModName,
            registrarModSurname: entry.registrarModSurname,
            registrarModId: entry.registrarModId,
            modificationDate: entry.modificationDate,
            state: entry.state
          };
        });
      console.log(this.history);
      this.history = this.history;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of history">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="[entry]">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="lp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>lp</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.lp }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="objectId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>objectId</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.objectId }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarName</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarName }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarSurname">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarSurname</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarSurname }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarId</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarId }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="entryDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>entryDate</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.entryDate }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarModName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarModName</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarModName }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarModSurname">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarModSurname</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarModSurname }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="registrarModId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>registrarModId</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.registrarModId }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="modificationDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>modificationDate</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.modificationDate }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>state</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.state }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is C# tag doing there?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you have an error? Does it display in a different way you intended? Please include all relevant details to the question so that we can help you. A test sample of the data can help too so we can test your code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current table template with the following code snippet. This iterates over each object's properties (one row for the name, and another row for the value).

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of history">
    <table mat-table>
        <tr *ngFor="let key of displayedColumns">
            <th mat-header-cell>{{ key }}</th>
            <td mat-cell>{{ entry[key] }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This will generate two rows for each field: the first row will display the field name (key) and the second row will display the field value. Both are aligned in the same column, as you desired

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work